# Python Multiprocessing: Sending data to a process

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have subclassed `Process` like so:

```
class EdgeRenderer(Process):
    def __init__(self,starter,*args,**kwargs):
        Process.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        self.starter=starter
```

Then I define a `run` method which uses `self.starter`.

That `starter` object is of a class `State` that I define.

Is it okay that I do this? What happens to the object? Does it get serialized? Does that mean that I always have to ensure the `State` object is serializable? Does the new process get a duplicate copy of this object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On unix systems, multiprocessing uses os.fork() to create the children, on windows, it uses some subprocess trickery and serialization to share the data. So to be cross platform, yes - it must be serializable. The child will get a new copy.

That being said, here's an example:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

class Starter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = False

x = Starter()

class EdgeRenderer(Process):
    def __init__(self,starter,*args,**kwargs):
        Process.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        self.starter=starter
    def run(self):
        self.starter.state = "HAM SANDWICH"
        time.sleep(1)
        print self.starter.state

a = EdgeRenderer(x)
a.start()
x.state = True
a.join()
print x.state
```

When run, you will see:

```
HAM SANDWICH
True
```

So the changes the parent makes don't get communicated after the fork() and the changes the child makes have the same issue. You have to adhere to fork limitations.

Comment: Okay, I understand. But that leaves one weird thing: When I pass a queue in the same way as I passed `starter`, it works, so I assume it does not get duplicated. So how come a normal object gets duplicated but a queue doesn't?

Comment: I assume you're talking about a multiprocessing.queue, which is handled differently than other objects, take a look at: http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/multiprocessing/queues.py?view=markup